# MongoDB Sharding, Replication and Clustering

Tags: mongodb

Based on my analysis below is understanding, correct me if my understating is wrong.

**Sharding** - Horizontal scaling, split the records into multiple chunks and store across multiple machine with good shard key for all collections.

**Replication** - Replicate the data across multiple machine for high availability

**Clustering** - As per Mongo architecture there will be one Master and multiple slave machine. Write and sensitive read operation performs against Master and read operation performs against slaves.

I am not able to correlate Clustering with Replication and Sharding, could you please someone guide me how to relate them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Term "clustering" is not normally used with mongodb. Instead, its meaning included in the term "sharding". A shard is a node/replicaset with only a portion of your data, yes. And cluster is simply a collection of shards (and supporting nodes, like config servers and mongos routers)

Whereas replication is done with replica sets, which have one primary node (master) and other nodes are secondaries (slaves).

Comment: One more clarification in shard, whether either each record of a collection will be chunked and store across shards or like first 10 record in shard1 and next 10 record in shard2?

Comment: @Pandian A document is never split in parts, no. It's the latter.